# Does vitest run --isolate=false influence the way that mocks are evaluated?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, vitest

I have (unfortunately) uncovered some flakiness in my tests. My colleague has recommended to me to run the tests in a few ways to try and flush out isolation issues and global pollution. One of his suggestions was to run tests with the `--isolate=false` flag enabled.

When doing this, I can inconsistently cause two tests to fail, but when they fail the reason is consistent. In both instances, the failure is related to mocked modules not actually being mocked.
One of the modules calls an external API, which, when the test fails, is calling the real API instead of the mocked response. When running the tests with `--isolate=true` the mocked module is called as expected.

The other module is google's protobuf timestamp, which, as with the other test, is calling the real module and not the mocked one when it fails. As before, when running the tests with isolation, nothing fails.

All mocked modules in question are done using the `__mocks__` folder. The path resolution must be correct, otherwise the tests would ordinarily fail due to the expect blocks not evaluating correctly.
All the tests in question routinely use `vi.clearAllMocks()` in `beforeEach` hooks, and use `vi.unstubAllGlobals()` and `vi.restoreAllMocks()` in `afterAll` hooks.

This is a real head scratcher for me. Any and all advice or questions are appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure this is definitively answerable given the best anyone can do is guess.  It's possible you can be resetting mocks from a state they are not set up correctly in each `beforeEach` for example.

Comment: @possum I'm not looking for a definitive answer, just a nudge in the right direction. Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'resetting mocks from a state they are not set up correctly in each beforeEach'?

Comment: You should read and understand the purpose of this site first.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  This isn't a general help or discussion forum.